# Python Crash course chapter 13-5, Sideways Shooter part 2, Only see few of aliens

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on my own version of this assignment and I am stuck. I created rows of devils (aliens) on the right side of the surface and they look fine until I update their position.

Once I run the `self.devils.update()` method to move them, suddenly I see 1 row of devils only on the screen, not all of them. They still do move up and down and also towards left once they touch the edge of the screen as I planned though.

To error check, I printed `len(self.devils)` to see if the number is matching with `self.devils` group, and they do match. I also muted `self.devils.update()` and I see all rows of devils again, just not moving.

How can I fix this?

Here is the main class, `heart_shooter.py'`:

```py
    def run_game(self):
        """ Start the main loop of the game """
        while True: 
            self._check_events()
            self.shooter.update()
            self._update_arrows()
            self._update_devils()
            self._update_screen()

    def _create_fleet(self):
        """ Create a fleet of devils. """
        # Create a devil and find the number of devils that fit on the screen.
        devil = Devil(self)
        devil_width, devil_height = devil.rect.size
        available_space_x = int((self.settings.screen_width / 2 ) + devil_width)
        number_devils_x=  available_space_x // (2 * devil_width)

        # Determine the number of rows of devils that fit on the screen.
        available_space_y = self.settings.screen_height - devil_height
        number_rows = available_space_y // (2 * devil_height)

        # Create a column of devils.
        for row_number in range (number_rows):
            for devil_number in range(number_devils_x):
                # Create a devil and place it in a row.
                self._create_devil(devil_number, row_number)

    def _create_devil(self,devil_number, row_number):
        """ Create a devil """
        devil = Devil(self)
        devil_width, devil_height = devil.rect.size
        available_space_x = (self.settings.screen_width / 2 ) 
        devil.x = available_space_x + ( 2 * devil_width * devil_number)
        devil.rect.x = devil.x
        devil.rect.y = devil_height + (2 * devil_height * row_number)

        self.devils.add(devil)

    def _check_fleet_edges(self):
        """ Respond appropriately if any devil reached the edge """
        for devil in self.devils.sprites():
            if devil.check_edges():
                self._change_fleet_direction()
                break

    def _change_fleet_direction(self):
        """ Move the fleet forward and change the direction. """
        for devil in self.devils.sprites():
            devil.rect.x -= self.settings.devil_forward_speed
        self.settings.fleet_direction *= -1


    def _update_devils(self):
        """
            Check if any devil has reached the edge of the screen 
                then update the position of the entire fleet.
        """
        self._check_fleet_edges()
        self.devils.update()
    
    def _update_screen(self):
        """ Update images on the screen and flip to the new screen. """
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.shooter.blitme()
        for arrow in self.arrows.sprites():
            arrow.draw_arrow()

        self.devils.draw(self.screen)

        # Make the most recently drawn screen visible
        pygame.display.flip()
```

This is the `devil.py`:

```
def __init__(self, hs_game):
    """ Initialize the devil and set its starting position"""
    super().__init__()
    self.screen = hs_game.screen
    self.screen_rect = hs_game.screen.get_rect()
    self.settings = hs_game.settings

    # Load the devil image and get its rect
    self.image = pygame.image.load('images/evil1.png')
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    # Start each new devil on the right top corner of the screen
    self.rect.x= self.screen_rect.width - (1.5 * self.rect.width)
    self.rect.y = self.screen_rect.top + (self.rect.height/2)

    # Store the exact vertical position of the devil
    self.y = float(self.rect.y)

def update(self):
    """ Move the devils up and down """
    self.y += (self.settings.devil_speed
                            * self.settings.fleet_direction)
    self.rect.y = self.y

def check_edges(self):
    """ Check if any devil have reached the bottom. """
    if self.rect.bottom >= self.screen_rect.bottom or self.rect.top <= 0:
        return True
```

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of PCC. I've looked at a lot of code like this over the years, and I can't spot anything here that would explain what you're seeing. When you say they all collapse to one row, is that a single horizontal row or is it actually a single column of devils? It's hard to diagnose some of this over SO. My email is in my profile, feel free to send a zip file of your full project and I'll help troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. The issue is solved but I am afraid that I still don't fully understand what made the difference.  I will send an email now with a file. (It was one horizontal row by the way. )

Answer (score 1):

For future readers of this post who are going through the same problem, I fixed the issue by the following change.

I changed the last 3 rows of `_create_devil()` method in `heart_shooter.py`.

```
    def _create_devil(self,devil_number, row_number):
        """ Create a devil """
        devil = Devil(self)
        devil_width, devil_height = devil.rect.size
        available_space_x = ((self.settings.screen_width / 2 ) 
                                                   + devil_width)
        devil.rect.x = available_space_x + ( 2 * devil_width * row_number)
        devil.y = devil_height + (2 * devil_height * devil_number)
        devil.rect.y = devil.y
```

Originally, I wrote below.

```
        devil.x = available_space_x + ( 2 * devil_width * devil_number)
        devil.rect.x = devil.x
        devil.rect.y = devil_height + (2 * devil_height * row_number)
```

(I will update this answer in elaborate detail later.)